# Named Imports are not working properly, Storybook adds everything present the folder to the bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, angular-storybook, storybook-addon

Whenever I use named imports, Storybook includes everything in the index file into the build, which eventually increases the bundle size.

main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.@(js|mdx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  features: {
    storyStoreV7: true,
  },
  core: {
    disableTelemetry: true,
  },
};
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.5",
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^5.0.1",
    "@dnd-kit/modifiers": "^5.0.0",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^6.0.0",
    "@dnd-kit/utilities": "^3.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.1.6",
    "highcharts": "^8.1.2",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.14",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-table-sticky": "^1.1.3",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.33.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators": "^7.12.1",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

My Folder structure looks like

```
src/
-images
   index.js
 - svgs/
   - index.js
   ...
   - noGoals/
     - index.js
     - NoGoals.js
     - NoGoals.svg
   - noUsers/
     - index.js
     - NoUsers.js
     - NoUsers.svg
  ...
```

All the main file in svgs folder, looks like this
Ex: images/svgs/noGoals/NoGoals.js

```
import React from "react";
import NoGoalsImg from "./NoGoals.svg";

const NoGoals = (props) => (
  <img src={NoGoalsImg} alt="NoGoalsImg" {...props} />
);

export default NoGoals;
```

and then I am exporting the Component in the index file

in index file

```
export { default } from "./NoGoals";
```

and in the end, I am export all the files like this in the images/svgs/index.js file

in images/svgs/index.js file

```
...
export { default as NoGoals } from "./noGoals";
export { default as NoTemplates } from "./noTemplates";
export { default as NoUsers } from "./noUsers";
...
```

Also, in images/index.js

```
export * from "svgs";
```

I have made a .mdx file and I am importing all one of the images using a named import like this

```
import { NoGoals } from "src/images";
```

After using this, at the build-storybook step, the storybook is including all the images & their content into the build, which increase the build size

You can notice here the all the bundles generated have the same size. ~3.02MB. it's like all my code is present in all my bundles.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlJm8.png)

Comment: Did you expect tree shaking?

Comment: @morganney  yes, Somewhat that kind. Also, the main issue is all my code is present in all of the bundles that are being generated so that you can see, all the bundles have almost the same size.  ~3.02MB

Comment: Did you use the `sideEffects` field in your package.json?

Comment: @morganney No, SideEffects field used.

Comment: You should read this https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free